# Selenium 4 no longer loading Firefox Driver

Tags: selenium

After updating a Java application based on Selenium to version 4, I found code packaged as an UberJar failed with the error:

```
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:230)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at com.octopus.decorators.FirefoxDecorator.init(FirefoxDecorator.java:72)
```

Interestingly all tests passed though. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because my application was packaged as an UberJAR with the Shade plugin. Selenium 4 must use a different service for locating dependencies based on service lookup, which requires META-INF/service files.

My configuration for building the UberJAR did not correctly capture these service files. The solution was to add the `ServicesResourceTransformer` to my Shade plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${shade.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```